# Error installing pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install a Pod (RegexKitLite) but I am facing this error. All other pods are being installed normally. This is what my Pods file looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

def import_pods
    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.23.0'
    pod 'CardIO', '5.0.2'
    pod 'CustomBadge', '3.0.0'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '3.10'
    pod 'GoogleConversionTracking', '3.2.0'
    pod 'NSData+Base64', '1.0.0'
    pod 'RegexKitLite', '4.0'
    pod 'SMXMLDocument', '1.0.1'
    pod 'SBJson', '4.0.1'
    pod 'XMLDictionary', '1.4'
    pod 'iAppInfos', '0.2.1'
    pod 'BSKeyboardControls', '2.2'
    pod 'FXBlurView', '1.6.3'
end

target :my_App do
    import_pods
end
```

and this is the error:

```
[!] Error installing RegexKitLite
[!] /usr/bin/svn export --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --force https://svn.code.sf.net/p/regexkit/code/RegexKitLite -r 69 /var/folders/d3/0wsknn2176q15z_yxfc_m0q5mc3l6_/T/d20150717-858-1i4ram4

svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/regexkit/code/RegexKitLite'

svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/regexkit/code/RegexKitLite': could not connect to server (https://svn.code.sf.net)
```

What should I do?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the site is down, you could try the RegexKitLite-NoWarning pod. This is a fork of RegexKitLite which fixes compilation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything but wait. https://svn.code.sf.net is down. You could contact the admin of course. The website says:

> The sourceforge.net website is temporarily in static offline mode.
>   Only a very limited set of project pages are available until the main website returns to service.